# Refactor class with more than 50k lines of code?

Tags: java

Hi to refactor code of 50k+ lines of code which one is better Inheritance or Composition.

My approach is as follows:

1. Create the subclass that will extend parent class(needs refactoring).
2. create interface for subclass
3. transfer the inner public methods to the child class that are also declared in interface of child class.

Now why this approach:
1.Parent Class want to refactor is @ManagedBean and spring @Component.

```
@Component
public class MBean extends ManagedBean{

@Autowired
transient SomeService someService;

private void calltoPriavateMethod(){
//100loc
}

public void calltoPublicMethod(){
//200loc
}

public void getExportJson(){

//100 loc

   try{
     calltoPrivateMethod()
   }catch(Exception e){
   //catch exception
   } 

   try{
     calltoPublicMethod()
   }catch(Exception e){
  //catch exception
  }
}
}
```

2. Solution I tried

```
public Interface ChildMBeanInterface{

calltoPublicMethod();

}

@Component
public class ChildMbean extend MBean implements ChildMBeanInterface{

calltoPublicMethod(){

//200 loc copied here
}

}

@Component
public class MBean extends ManagedBean{

@Autowired
transient SomeService someService;

@Autowired
ChildMBeanInterface childMBeanInterface;


public void getExportJson(){

//100 loc

   try{
     calltoPrivateMethod()
   }catch(Exception e){
   //catch exception
   } 

   try{
     childMBeanInterface.calltoPublicMethod()
   }catch(Exception e){
  //catch exception
  }
}

}
```

JSF CODE : is directly calling getExportJson()

```
<p:commandLink id="exportCaseWithJsonId"
                                            value="Export Data" partialSubmit="true"
                                            onclick="PF('statusDialog').show();"

                                            action="#{MBean.getExportCaseJSON}" process="@this"
                                            immediate="true">
```

So my is Question my class structure looks like this ? Is my approach is fine or it can be improved. Please give suggestions.

MBean is JSF managed Bean and this contains many other functions for different services.function that are called from jsf are public, however some inner method calls are private as well as public.

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad, because 50K lines of code is logically too big for a single question IMHO.  You should first step back and tell us what this class does, and how the various pieces of functionality might be refactored out to other classes.

Comment: The possibility that these methods use common variables is pretty high, right? So you cannot simply move every method to a new class...

Comment: if we consider very general case of refactoring what is better inheritance or composition.?any refactoring tools i can use?

Comment: and also these methods use many  common variables.

Answer (score 1):

In general, **favor [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)**. Inheritance has many limitations that don't apply to composition, and it can make things way too complicated.

Before getting started, you need to know which parts can be seperated. Take a piece of paper, map out the usages of your fields and the relations of the methods. Try to determine which parts are isolated. Then move that part to a different class. (And obviously, you can't isolate parts of code that call methods or use fields of the super class).

Here is an example of a piece of code that contains a lot of code regarding listeners.

```
class Foo {
  List<Listener> listeners;
  // and 101 other fields

  public void addListener(...) { }
  public boolean removeListener(...) { }
  private void notifyListeners(...) { }
  // and 101 other mthods

  private void somethingHappens() {
    notifyListeners();
  } 
}
```

In a case like this you could regard the listeners part as an isolated feature of the class. **The fields and methods which are used by this part of code, are not used by other methods, meaning you could isolate them.**

So, you could move them to a new "feature class" named `Listeners` for example.

```
class Listeners() {
  List<Listener> listeners;

  public void add(...) { ... }
  public boolean remove(...) { ... }
  public void notifyListeners(...) { ... }
}
```

Now, in the original class, most code dissapears.

```
class Foo {
  Listeners listeners = new Listeners();

  public Listeners getListeners() { ... }

  private void somethingHappens() {
    listeners.notifyListeners();
  } 
}
```

*(Note: the `new Listeners()` could also go in a `protected createListeners()` method, which still allows subclasses to override the behavior which you just isolated.)*

Your class gets a lot thinner. But it does mean that the usages and signatures change a little. i.e. `addListener(...)` vs `getListeners().add(...)`. And that may be a problem.

So, before you get started, **you should determine if that is a problem or not**. For internal usage this can't be a problem. But if you implemented an interface it certainly will be.

You could just add thin wrapper methods that forward requests. But often this won't be a big step forward. You moved some code, and you added some new. You may end up wondering if it's worth it. It's a trade-off worth considering if there are a lot of private methods and only a limited amount of public ones.

Alternatively, sometimes with legacy code, **you may just chose to divide your classes in collapsable sections**. That in itself can be a step forward.